# azure Loganalytics with API connection

Tags: azure, api, rest, post, get

I have to use the command for log analytics API from azure to get access token, however, didn't respond.
use the value accordingly, anything needs to add other than the value as follows.

> ```
>        POST /e7xxxxxxx/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
> ```

```
         Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
         Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

         grant_type=client_credentials
         &client_id=03xxxxxxxxxx
         &redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/login
         &resource=https://api.loganalytics.io
         &client_secret=xxxxxx
```

this command supposes to respond 200 ok which is given you an "access token" but the command stays and responds nothing. if you have any suggestions or recommendations on how to use LogAnalytics with API that will be very helpful.

Comment: Remove `&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/login` and try again.

Comment: I have tried but the same. thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Where did you send the request, could you use postman to have a try? It works on my side.

Comment: I didn't try POSTMAN used  Linux box. so just paste the whole code on POST man without the line redirect? or other things need to POSTMAN.  thanks much!!

Comment: Yes, just follow my sample below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [client credential flow v1.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), the `redirect_uri` is not needed, you could use postman to get the token, you could refer to the sample below which works for me.

[image]